# React Native newbie

Tags: xcode, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I want to build a game with React Native. I am doing my testing locally on a personal Android device using the Expo app but ideally would love for the app to be cross platform. I do want to release it to a public store or have it be available for folks to play in some format.

Is it OK if I am using Visual Studio Code (on a Windows machine) to build my app, using node.js command line to run expo commands and testing with live reloading on my Expo app? Do I need to have a Mac + XCode if I want to edit iOS code?

What is the typical development process/toolset used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native IS cross-platform, building the apps for production on different platforms, however, requires a different procedure. What makes it cross platform is that you write the source codes including all of the components (Well most of them) one time, and it automatically generates the native codes for Android and IOS.

There's no typical toolset for writing code, you can use any code editor you prefer (I use Sublime for example), but you should have the needed requirements listed in the getting started page in the official [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) including node.js.

Expo helps in testing the app on both android and ios without the need of a Mac (it has some other cool features too!). So if you want to release to apple store, you'll definitely need a mac (or a virtual machine running MacOS like VMWare)

In order to generate the release apk for android: [Android Release APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-the-release-apk)

and for IOS: [IOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)